# QTKit A file or directory could not be found

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, qtkit

I'm trying to record and play movies with my app using qtkit. I record the video in one view and display it into another view. Here's how I do it

```
- (void)startRecording
{
    NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] applicationSupportDirectory];
    NSString *path = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kVideoOutputName];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    // Delete the previous file
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:nil];

    mCaptureMovieFileOutput.delegate = self;
    [mCaptureMovieFileOutput recordToOutputFileURL:url];
}

- (void)stopRecording
{
    [mCaptureMovieFileOutput recordToOutputFileURL:nil];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(QTCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL forConnections:(NSArray *)connections dueToError:(NSError *)error
{
    // [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:outputFileURL];

    // removes the current view
    [self cleanView];

    MyViewController *controller = [[SharingViewController alloc] init];
    controllerpath.path = outputFileURL;

    [self.view addSubview:[controller view]];

    [self stopCamera];
}
```

Now in my view controller I assign the movie to my movie player.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSError *error;
    moviePlayer.movie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:path error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Now, this code works the first time around, but I need to register and show multiple times.

There's already one problem here. If I want to record videos multiple times, I have to delete the first one, otherwise after the first time it wont record anything (it complains that a file already exists).

The problem is that after the first time, it also doesn't show the video at all. When I execute [QTMovie movieWithURL:path error:&error]; it complains that the file or directory does not exists, when in reality it does (I also checked with [QTMovie canInitWithUrl:]).

I'm not sure what's going on here. The apple's sample code is able to record multiple times, but for some reasons I can't without first deleting the existing file (it works the first time, though).

I'd be happy to provide further details if needed.

EDIT: If I use a different name every time for the video, everything works. So this is really an issue about recording with the same name every time.

Comment: Sounds like there's some crazy caching going on. Did you try using `alloc/initWithURL:error:` instead of the convenience method? Or, if that failed as well, creating an editable movie which is kept around for the lifetime of this recording/playback task and whose URL you simply update by setting it to `nil` when you delete the old file?

Comment: In any case: did you file a bug with a reduced sample project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different file name for every file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and I found that setting the movie view to nil, prior to reusing the same file name resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same weird problem creating a QTMovie. I just loaded the file to an NSData object like this and it worked:

```
[self setMovieData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[self movieURL]]];
[self setMovie:[QTMovie movieWithData:[self movieData] error:&error]];
```